# Modifying the following regex to include a slash at the end of the URL

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regex matches the last word in the URL:

```
var match = (location.search.match(/(\w+)$/))
  ? location.search.match(/(\w+)$/)[0] 
  : "";
```

The problem is that sometimes the URL will look like this `www.mysite.com/match-last-word/` so `word` isn't matched because there's a slash at the end.

I tried this:

```
var match = (location.search.match(/(\w+)$\/*/))
  ? location.search.match(/(\w+)$\/*/)[0] 
  : "";
```

But didn't work.

Comment: It probably didn't work because `\/*` appears after the anchor, `$`.  The dollars sign means end of string, so putting anything after it could cause the regex to behave in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the pattern `\W*` at the last to match zero or more non-word characters.

```
\b(\w+)\W*$
```

**OR**

```
\b\w+(?=\W*$)
```

`(?=\W*$)` positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match `\w+` must be followed by `\W*`, zero or more non-word characters and further followed by the line end.

**Example:**

```
> var s = "www.mysite.com/match-last-word/"
undefined
> s.match(/\b\w+(?=\W*$)/)[0]
'word'
```

Comment: yours is the only one that worked because the other's also matched the `/`. Thanks, could you explain briefly what `?=` does in that regex?

Comment: @alexchenco It's a look-ahead assertion, which means that matching is performed without becoming part of the match itself; the advantage is that you don't need a memory capture (like in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var match = (location.search.match(/(\w+|\w+\/)$/))
  ? location.search.match(/(\w+|\w+\/)$/))[0] 
  : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match something *after* `$` (which in this case represents the end-of-subject) whereas you should match before:

```
location.search.match(/(\w+)\/?$/)
```

I've made the match optional so that it matches with or without a trailing slash. To find the matched word:

```
location.search.match(/(\w+)\/?$/)[1];
```

Example:

```
> '?text=word/'.match(/(\w+)\/$/)
["word/", "word"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`location.search` gives you the query parameters of a url.  If the url is `example.com/whatever/?q=123&name=something`, then location.search will give you everything after the question mark.  However, if the url is something like `example.com/whatever/`, then location.search won't give you anything at all.  So when you do `location.search.match()`, you're searching for something that doesn't exist.

If you want to reliably find the last word in a path name (example.com/asdf/targetword), then use this:
`location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+($|(?=\/$))/i)[0]`

Basically, it looks for the final set of non-slash characters in a url path.

This also works if it's hyphenated.  For example, `example.com/asdf/longer-title/` will give you `longer-title`.

Answer (score 0):

what you tried did not work because the $ represents the END of the line, so you cannot have / AFTER it. if you correct it by moving the /* to before the $, it should work the way you are trying it:

```
var match = (location.search.match(/(\w+)\/*$/))
? location.search.match(/(\w+)\/*$/)[0] 
: "";
```